# Pandas: create dataframe using value_counts

Tags: python, pandas

I have data

```
age
32
16
39
39
23
36
29
26
43
34
35
50
29
29
31
42
53
```

I need to get smth like this
[image]
I can get

`df.age.value_counts()`
and

```
100. * df.age.value_counts() / len(df.age)
```

But how can I union this and give name to columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) with [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
#helper df with min and max ages, necessary add category Total
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'G':['14 yo and younger','15-19','20-24','25-29','30-34',
                         '35-39','40-44','45-49','50-54','55-59','60-64','65+','Total'], 
                     'Min':[0, 15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,np.nan], 
                     'Max':[14,19,24,29,34,39,44,49,54,59,64,120, np.nan]})

print (df1)
                    G    Max   Min
0   14 yo and younger   14.0   0.0
1               15-19   19.0  15.0
2               20-24   24.0  20.0
3               25-29   29.0  25.0
4               30-34   34.0  30.0
5               35-39   39.0  35.0
6               40-44   44.0  40.0
7               45-49   49.0  45.0
8               50-54   54.0  50.0
9               55-59   59.0  55.0
10              60-64   64.0  60.0
11                65+  120.0  65.0
12              Total    NaN   NaN
```

```
cutoff = np.hstack([np.array(df1.Min[0]), df1.Max.values])
labels = df1.G.values

df['Groups'] = pd.cut(df.age, bins=cutoff, labels=labels, right=True, include_lowest=True)
print (df)
    age Groups
0    32  30-34
1    16  15-19
2    39  35-39
3    39  35-39
4    23  20-24
5    36  35-39
6    29  25-29
7    26  25-29
8    43  40-44
9    34  30-34
10   35  35-39
11   50  50-54
12   29  25-29
13   29  25-29
14   31  30-34
15   42  40-44
16   53  50-54
```

```
df = df.groupby('Groups')['Groups']
       .agg({'Total':[len, lambda x: len(x)/df.shape[0] * 100 ]})
       .rename(columns={'len':'N', '<lambda>':'%'})

#last Total row
df.ix['Total'] = df.sum()

print (df)    
                 Total            
                      N           %
Groups                             
14 yo and younger   0.0    0.000000
15-19               1.0    5.882353
20-24               1.0    5.882353
25-29               4.0   23.529412
30-34               3.0   17.647059
35-39               4.0   23.529412
40-44               2.0   11.764706
45-49               0.0    0.000000
50-54               2.0   11.764706
55-59               0.0    0.000000
60-64               0.0    0.000000
65+                 0.0    0.000000
Total              17.0  100.000000
```

EDIT1:

Solution with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) scale better:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Groups').size().to_frame()
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(('Total','N'))
df1.ix[:,('Total','%')] = 100 * df1.ix[:,('Total','N')] / df.shape[0]
df1.ix['Total'] = df1.sum()
print (df1)
                  Total            
                      N           %
Groups                             
14 yo and younger   0.0    0.000000
15-19               1.0    5.882353
20-24               1.0    5.882353
25-29               4.0   23.529412
30-34               3.0   17.647059
35-39               4.0   23.529412
40-44               2.0   11.764706
45-49               0.0    0.000000
50-54               2.0   11.764706
55-59               0.0    0.000000
60-64               0.0    0.000000
65+                 0.0    0.000000
Total              17.0  100.000000
```

Comment: Is it `%`? I should get 100%. And how can I add at the bottom total and 100%?

Comment: Sorry, it was more complicated, but now answer is edited.

Comment: Why I get an error `TypeError: cannot append a non-category item to a CategoricalIndex` when I use `age = df.groupby('Groups')['Groups'].agg({'Total': [len, lambda x: len(x) / df.shape[0] * 100]}).rename(columns={'len': 'N', '<lambda>': '%'})
` and next `age.ix['Total'] = age.sum()`?

Comment: Because my first version mising last value `Total` in `df1`, please use last version where it works correctly.

Comment: I only want to give name `age` to df, because I need next in `df`

Comment: Ok, but in `df` (with `Total`) are aggreagted values, so you need add aggreagte column `age`? If yes, do you need aggregate by mean or sum?

Comment: I need your result, but I want `age = df.groupby('Groups')['Groups'].agg({'Total': [len, lambda x: len(x) / df.shape[0] * 100]}).rename(columns={'len': 'N', '<lambda>': '%'})`. `age.ix['Total'] = df.sum()` it works too long. (now it's working 15 minutes and doesn't end)

Comment: What is `length` of `DataFrame`?

Comment: `Exception Exception: Exception('Exception caught in workbook destructor. Explicit close() may be required for workbook.',) in <bound method Workbook.__del__ of <xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook object at 0x000000000A3F7A20>> ignored
`

Comment: It looks like some problem with excel. Can you simulate it?

Comment: I forgot to close excel. Now I try again and in return `TypeError: cannot append a non-category item to a CategoricalIndex`

Comment: Do you use `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'G':['14 yo and younger','15-19','20-24','25-29','30-34',
                         '35-39','40-44','45-49','50-54','55-59','60-64','65+','Total'], 
                     'Min':[0, 15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,np.nan], 
                     'Max':[14,19,24,29,34,39,44,49,54,59,64,120, np.nan]})` ?

Comment: It doesnt work wit sample data or with real data or both?

Comment: It fail only in `df1.ix['Total'] = df1.sum()` ?

Comment: I think I had an error with excel. Now it works. Thank you for your help so much!

Comment: can you say, with me data it doesn't return 100%, why can it happen? How can I change that?

Comment: I see your question a few hour ago and I think there is problem with float point accuracy. Better it is explain [here](http://floating-point-gui.de/).